# Removing three bar menu navicon from wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, hamburger-menu

Hi and thanks for taking the time to consider this question. Firstly, I must mention I am by no means a programmer - I've only been messing around for a couple of weeks.

I spent last night trying to design a website for my fiance's cleaning business. I eventually decided on the free Vantage Wordpress theme to start with. As the menu in that version is not responsive, I copied the following code from a siteorigin thread:

```
/* Mobile Nav */

.mobile-nav-frame {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}

.mobile-nav-frame .title h3 {
color: black !important;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}

.mobile-nav-frame ul {
background: #ffffff !important;
border: 1px solid #111 !important;
}

.mobile-nav-frame ul li {
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) !important;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) !important;
}

.mobile-nav-frame ul li a.link {
color: #3ab2c0 !important;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}
```

It worked and I got a hamburger menu except that a copy of the same menu names displayed in the body of the document. I eventually discovered that Vantage Premium has responsive menus and upgraded. I've now got the Vantage Premium mobile menu on my phone but the first hamburger menu I put on is still there and won't go away.

I tried deleting all the vantage files off my web server, then uploading again but that didn't help. I also tried clearing the cache on my phone but that didn't help. Finally, I went through the entire style.css document but didn't see anything unusual as I'd already deleted the previous hamburger menu's code.

Any help that you could provide would be most assisted as my fiance just paid for hosting and I told her I'd make her a responsive website.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Mark Beaton

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mark. It does sound like a cache issue to me, even tho you said you've cleared it. The code you provided is not sufficient. Could you share a live demo for us to properly inspect?

Comment: Press `CTRL + U` find `style.css` URL then click it. Once opened press `F5`